# Skip Over Words/Phrases if In Quotes while doing String Replacement/Removal

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

Let's say I have a string like this

> I am flying from "Detroit to Vancouver" this July

```
$string = 'I am flying from "Detroit to Vancouver" this July';
```

I also have an array of "`stopwords`" (words that I'm choosing to remove from the string/strings)

```
$stopwords = array( "to", "anotherstopword", "andanother" )
```

Right now I'm just using

```
$string = str_replace($stopwords, ' ', $string);
```

This of course gives me `string(33) "I am flying from "Detroit Vancouver" this July"`

I was thinking about maybe exploding the `$string` with a space before the `str_replace`, giving me something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => I
    [1] => am
    [2] => flying
    [3] => from
    [4] => "Detroit
    [5] => to
    [6] => Vancouver"
    [7] => this
    [8] => July
)
```

Then perhaps removing them from the array, doing the replace, and re-inserting them.. but this seems overkill

I've also thought about using a function like this

```
  function getStringBetween($str, $from, $to, $withFromAndTo = false)
  {
      $sub = substr($str, strpos($str, $from) + strlen($from), strlen($str));
      if ($withFromAndTo)
          return $from . substr($sub, 0, strrpos($sub, $to)) . $to;
      else
          return substr($sub, 0, strrpos($sub, $to));
  }
```

When doing so,

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(getStringBetween($string, '"', '"'));
    echo '</pre>';
```

Outputs:

> Detroit to Vancouver

And doing some type of ignore condition before the str_replace..

But this fails whenever there are multiple quotations in the string..

Ideally I would like to create a condition to where if the string contains double quotes, to ignore them entirely in the `str_replace` process.

I am of course not opposed to using something other than str_replace, like preg_replace, but I do not have enough experience with that to produce a sample for my expected output.

Can anyone think of a good way to ignore stop words/words to be removed before doing the replace?

EDIT:

Code Sample

```
<?php

  $stopwordstest = array( " to ", " a ", " test " );

  $string = 'I am flying from "Detroit to Vancouver" this July when the weather is test nice';

  var_dump($string);

// as is, without string replace
// string(79) "I am flying from "Detroit to Vancouver" this July when the weather is test nice" 

  $string = str_replace($stopwordstest, ' ', $string);

  echo '<br><br>';

  var_dump($string);

// string(71) "I am flying from "Detroit Vancouver" this July when the weather is nice"

// Expected output is:
//
// string(74) "I am flying from "Detroit to Vancouver" this July when the weather is nice"
//

?>
```

In other words, I'd like the string replacement to go forth as intended, but since the word `to` is encapsulated in quotes (`"Detroit to Vancouver"`), it should skip this word because it is in quotes.

Comment: I think you missed a step in your explanation: with your example inputs, what do you want the outputs to be?  If you give 2 or 3 example inputs and their desired outputs I can probably help.

Comment: Added a code sample.. If it is not clear all I am simply trying to do is a str_replace or preg_replace function to remove an array of words that are NOT in doublequotes... if a group of words is encapsulated in quotes, I'd like it to remain unmodified or skipped in my replacement method.

Comment: does your string always look like this ? I mean it has only one part containing "" or it may have multiple parts with ""?

Comment: As of now I am only encountering one parts containing double-quotes but I'd like to have it so that if there are multiple it can accomodate... check out @revo answer it seems to be a great solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easy using Regular Expressions, more easier using PHP (PCRE). With PCRE you have this ability to match and skip using `(*SKIP)` backtracking verb. You match a double-quoted string then make engine to skip this part from overall match and type your desired pattern in second side of alternation.

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)
```

Above regex matches a double quoted string (including escaped double quotation marks) and then tells engine to forget.

This would be the PHP code that implements this feature along with gathering stop words within a regex:

```
echo preg_replace('/"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(?:'
    . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $stopwords))
    . ')\b\h*/', '', $string);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/e8Mee)

Comment: YES! That works brilliantly. That regex is so crazy it would have taken me days to even get a grasp around it. Need to give it a real in-depth look one of these days because the possibilities (as shown) are very effective! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($stopwords as &$stopword) {
    $string = str_replace($stopword, ' ', $string);
}
```

Comment: Not sure about how this is supposed to work, but it is still removing the words in double-quotes.  Using the edited sample the output is the same `string(71) "I am flying from "Detroit Vancouver" this July when the weather is nice"` as a normal `str_replace`

Comment: yep , sorry I made a mistake

Comment: Thanks for trying the `&$` operator is an interesting (possible) option nonetheless